# What was Blake picking up at the end of the movie?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

At the end of *The Dark Knight Rises* we see Blake (Joseph Gordon-Levitt) approach a woman and pick something up, using his full name. What was he picking up, and from whom?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It was what Bruce bequeathed to him.  After Bruce and Blake's discussions, Bruce decided to leave the job of Batman to Blake.  Bruce updated his will to give Blake that duffel bag (while apparently not adjusting the rest of the will to reflect his lost wealth).  Inside, Bruce provided Blake with coordinates and gear to get into the Batcave.

Comment: You see Blake carrying the duffel bag as he enters the Bat Cave, before tacking gear out of it.

Answer (score 4):

At the very least, it revealed to him the existence and location of the Batcave. Whether or not it contained anything else is probably not, and will not be known.